# Jewish and Muslim holidays formula

Tags: calendar

Is there a ready-to-use formula in LaTeX for Jewish or Muslim holidays, like this one for the Christian holidays:
https://texample.net/tikz/examples/birthday-calendar/

This is a formula for the Jewish holidays in PHP (http://www.david-greve.de/luach-code/jewish-php.html#holidays) but I wonder whether it already exists somewhere in LaTeX.

Comment: Possibly you’d find it useful to see how the Emacs calendar handles these holidays: https://repo.or.cz/emacs.git/tree/HEAD:/lisp/calendar